# What is String.CopyTo?

Tags: c#

Can any one explain why the output of this code is only 'hello' and what this code means?

```
( 0, characterArray, 0, characterArray.Length );
```

The output is showing:

```
The character array is: hello
```

The code follows:

```
string string1 = "hello there";
char[] characterArray = new char[ 5 ];

string1.CopyTo( 0, characterArray, 0, characterArray.Length );
Console.Write( "\nThe character array is: " );

for ( int i = 0; i < characterArray.Length; i++ )
    Console.Write( characterArray[ i ] );
```

Comment: Your title should really be much more explicit about what this question actually is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your array is only set for 5 characters. Expand it to 11 and it will work.

Here is what the Copyto is:

```
public void CopyTo(
    int sourceIndex,
    char[] destination,
    int destinationIndex,
    int count
)
```

```
Parameters
sourceIndex
Type: System..::.Int32
A character position in this instance. 

destination
Type: array[]()[]
An array of Unicode characters. 

destinationIndex
Type: System..::.Int32
An array element in destination. 

count
Type: System..::.Int32
The number of characters in this instance to copy to destination.
```

Taken from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.copyto.aspx

Comment: What does this mean sweety ( 0, characterArray, 0, characterArray.Length );

Answer (score 2):

It's only showing 'hello' because your character array is only 5 chars long.  As for the parameters to CopyTo, read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.copyto.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That's because your character array size is only 5. if you want the whole string as an array, you can you string.ToCharArray instead